# Equality Operator subtle differences

Tags: java

Why does the `if` conditional evaluate to `true` in this program? How is `10` equivalent to `10.0`?

```
 public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int i = 10;
         double d = 10.0;

         if (i == d) {
             System.out.println("hi");
         } else {
             System.out.println("bye");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i == d` is the same as `(double) i == d` or `i - d == 0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) rules described in Java Language Specification, section 5.6.2. These rules apply to the binary operations on numbers of different type. It says that:

> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

Answer (score 3):

`int` will be converted into `double` when we compare int with double. see this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1

Comment: This chapter refers to `</>/<=/>=` operations, not to `==`.